# Connection is not available, request timed out after 30003ms

Tags: java, connection, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I'm getting this exception for last few days.

This problem occurs when I process 10++ form and connection keep on increasing every 30 seconds to 1 minute 30 seconds until reach max size.

I've ensure all connection already close. 
Why am I keep getting this error?

**Environment:**

- HikariCP version: 2.5.1
- JDK version: 1.8.0_152
- Database: MySQL

I keep on getting this error:

```html
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: ConcolePool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30003ms.
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
 at org.apache.jsp.utilBillParaList_jsp._jspService(utilBillParaList_jsp.java:761)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
 ... 51 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: ConcolePool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30003ms.
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:548)
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145)
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
 at org.apache.jsp.utilBillParaList_jsp._jspService(utilBillParaList_jsp.java:322)
```

**Configuration:**

```html
09:05:37,908 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :841 - ConcolePool - configuration:
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - allowPoolSuspension.............false
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - autoCommit......................true
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - catalog.........................null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - connectionInitSql...............null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - connectionTestQuery............."SELECT current_timestamp"
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - connectionTimeout...............30000
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - dataSource......................null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - dataSourceClassName............."com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - dataSourceJNDI..................null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - dataSourceProperties............{port=3307, user=root, password=<masked>, prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048, cachePrepStmts=true, prepStmtCacheSize=500, serverName=localhost}
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - driverClassName.................null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - healthCheckProperties...........{}
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - healthCheckRegistry.............null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - idleTimeout.....................600000
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - initializationFailFast..........true
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - isolateInternalQueries..........false
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - jdbcUrl.........................null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - leakDetectionThreshold..........30000
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - maxLifetime.....................1800000
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - maximumPoolSize.................10
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - metricRegistry..................null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - metricsTrackerFactory...........null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - minimumIdle.....................5
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - password........................<masked>
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - poolName........................"ConcolePool"
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - readOnly........................false
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - registerMbeans..................false
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - scheduledExecutorService........null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - threadFactory...................null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - transactionIsolation............null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - username........................null
09:05:37,924 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig :857 - validationTimeout...............5000
09:05:37,924  INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource :70 - ConcolePool - Started.
```

**Debug for pool status:**

```html
2018-05-14 12:48:19  [ ConcolePool connection adder:5403109 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - After adding stats (total=5, active=0, idle=5, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:48:49  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5433109 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=5, active=1, idle=4, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:48:49  [ ConcolePool connection adder:5433109 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Added connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@39193bcd
2018-05-14 12:48:49  [ ConcolePool connection adder:5433109 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - After adding stats (total=6, active=1, idle=5, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:49:07  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5450750 ] - [ WARN ]  Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@160af66e, stack trace follows
2018-05-14 12:49:19  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5463125 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=6, active=1, idle=5, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:49:49  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5493140 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=6, active=2, idle=4, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:49:49  [ ConcolePool connection adder:5493140 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Added connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@207b7ac0
2018-05-14 12:49:49  [ ConcolePool connection adder:5493140 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - After adding stats (total=7, active=2, idle=5, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:49:54  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5497687 ] - [ WARN ]  Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@10429350, stack trace follows
2018-05-14 12:50:19  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5523156 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=7, active=2, idle=5, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:50:49  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5553172 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=7, active=3, idle=4, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:50:49  [ ConcolePool connection adder:5553172 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Added connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@4721d5d3
2018-05-14 12:50:49  [ ConcolePool connection adder:5553172 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - After adding stats (total=8, active=3, idle=5, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:50:58  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5561656 ] - [ WARN ]  Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@76ff6438, stack trace follows
2018-05-14 12:51:19  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5583187 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=8, active=4, idle=4, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:51:19  [ ConcolePool connection adder:5583187 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Added connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@1f4c60a8
2018-05-14 12:51:19  [ ConcolePool connection adder:5583187 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - After adding stats (total=9, active=4, idle=5, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:51:42  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5606359 ] - [ WARN ]  Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@1cff4d1c, stack trace follows
2018-05-14 12:51:49  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5613203 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=9, active=4, idle=5, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:52:19  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5643219 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=9, active=4, idle=5, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:52:49  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5673234 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=9, active=5, idle=4, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:52:49  [ ConcolePool connection adder:5673234 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Added connection com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2d750b07
2018-05-14 12:52:49  [ ConcolePool connection adder:5673234 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - After adding stats (total=10, active=5, idle=5, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:52:53  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5676453 ] - [ WARN ]  Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@708cdc47, stack trace follows
2018-05-14 12:53:19  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5703250 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=6, idle=4, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:53:43  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5726594 ] - [ WARN ]  Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@39193bcd, stack trace follows
2018-05-14 12:53:49  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5733265 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=6, idle=4, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:54:19  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5763281 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=7, idle=3, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:54:39  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5782984 ] - [ WARN ]  Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@207b7ac0, stack trace follows
2018-05-14 12:54:49  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5793297 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=7, idle=3, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:55:19  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5823312 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=8, idle=2, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:55:45  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5848906 ] - [ WARN ]  Connection leak detection triggered for com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@4721d5d3, stack trace follows
2018-05-14 12:55:49  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5853328 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=8, idle=2, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:56:19  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5883344 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=8, idle=2, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:56:49  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5913359 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=8, idle=2, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:57:20  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5943375 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=8, idle=2, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:57:50  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:5973390 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=8, idle=2, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:58:20  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:6003406 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=8, idle=2, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:58:50  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:6033422 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=8, idle=2, waiting=0)
2018-05-14 12:59:20  [ ConcolePool housekeeper:6063437 ] - [ DEBUG ]  ConcolePool - Pool stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=1)
```

How to troubleshoot this problem? Is there something I need to change?

**Edit:**

```
public Connection getConnection(){
    try{
        return datas.getConnection();

    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        datas.resumePool();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Example close connection:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    DataSource datas = (DataSource) getServletContext().getAttribute("ds");
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try{
        conn = datas.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        //some sql
        //process form
        //pass the return values

        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you handle your connections, especially where you close it?

Comment: thanks for your respond. I've edit the post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't closing the connections always and therefore the connection pool reaches its limits.

You **must** close connection and statement when finished block (as all resources), also if an exception occurred, The right/easy way is with [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) approach:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

  DataSource datas = (DataSource) getServletContext().getAttribute("ds");

  try (Connection conn = datas.getConnection();Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()){
    

    //some sql
    //process form
    //pass the return values

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

> The try-with-resources Statement
> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.